# validating dxtextbox using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, devextreme

I am trying to validate a text box where user will only be allowed to enter alphabets,number,and few special characters like !, @, #, $, %, &, * currently I tried only [a-zA-Z0-9] which accepts only alphabets And number,can someone please suggest me a regex which will help me to get the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%&*]+$/g` should work for you.  This will validate if the the complete string is composed of one or more characters found within the square brackets.

To familiarize yourself with some regular expressions syntax and meaning, I would suggest using [RegExr](http://regexr.com/3dmbh).  This provides an online validator, explains each element of the expression and has helpful tips/examples in the side bar to help with expression building.

Comment: Thanks for the help,I want to know one more thing that if i am validating username then what are all the symbols in order to block cross side scripting

Comment: That's a rather significant question and definitely warrants some research and its own post.  I would suggest providing more information about where this username is being used (MySQL DB, datastore, etc.).  As a general convention, usernames tend to start with alphanumeric characters and can include a few extra characters like `.`, `-` and `_`.  They usually also have character limits (min/max).  I would also suggest reading up on security best practices.

Answer (score 0):

/[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%]$/g.test('aaaaa!jbhjj@@@')